# iOS7 searchBar and tableView cells have gap when searchDisplayController is active

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` within my `UITableView`. When the `UISearchBarController` is activated, the table view does not move up with the search bar, instead a gap is left between them.

[image: 1. Gap between Search Bar with Scope Bar and Table View]

Even if I get rid of the scope bar, the gap still exists as below:

[image: 2. Gap between Search Bar and Table View]

Here is a link to sample project I was using https://github.com/msec/TestSearchDisplayController

Note this gap does not appear in the apple mail and contacts app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add your searchBar in tableView Header

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Comment: I tried adding this in and it didn't work, sorry I forgot to include a link to the sample project. It is now included above if you want to try and use that

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing 2 lines in my code.

`self.viewcontroller.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`
`self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Also to note, I have my search bar in the table view header view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed adding this line to the viewDidLoad

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having the `UISearchBar` stay in the same place (instead of moving up), you can set
`searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` in `viewDidLoad`